# Ввод данных с клавиатуры - Rust

Tags: input, rust

Здравствуйте! Как я могу считать данные вводимые пользователем с клавиатуры? Здесь также задан [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13579266/how-to-read-user-input-in-rust), но предложенные способы очень неудобны. Можно ли как-то считать строку в стиле Python (`input()`) или C++/Си (`cin`/`scanf()`)? А если нет, то как сделать это более удобным способом?

### UPD

Нашел [это](https://github.com/oli-obk/rust-si). Подключаю к проекту:

```
[dependencies.text_io]
version = "*"
features = ["nightly"]
```

Но к сожалению уверенно отказывается компилироваться `quasi v0.3.0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Написал небольшую функцию:

```
fn read_string(comment:&str) -> String {
    println!("{}", comment);
    let mut string: String = String::new();

    std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut string)
        .ok()
        .expect("Error read line!");

    return string;
}
```

Если вместо `return string` написать `return string.trim().parse::<i32>().unwrap();` можно получить тип `i32`, а по аналогии - все остальные.
Теперь можно писать так: `let number:i32 = read_i32("Input number: ");`
Пока не знаю, как выполнить чтение на одной строке с желаемым тектом, т.е при использовании примера выше:

```
Input number: 
(здесь вводится текст)
```

## UPD

Чтобы текст вводился на одной строке с комментарием к нему модифицируйте функцию:

```
use std::io::Write;
use std::io;

fn read_string(comment:&str) -> String {
    print!("{}", comment);
    io::stdout().flush();

    let mut string: String = String::new();

    io::stdin().read_line(&mut string)
        .ok()
        .expect("Error read line!");

    return string;
}
```

Comment: _Пока не знаю, как выполнить чтение на одной строке с желаемым тектом_    использовать `print!` вместо `println!`, возможно вместе с `io::stdout().flush()`

Comment: Если использовать `print!` то сначала происходит чтение строки, а на следующей строке вывод текста. Не могли бы Вы по подробнее объяснить про `io::stdout().flush()`, в `std` такого нет. Есть только `std::io::Write.flush()`, но я не понял, как это использовать.

Comment: `std::io::stdout()` - функция, возвращающая объект типа `std::io::Stdout` который имплементирует в том числе `std::io::Write`
модификацию вашей функции с `print!` вместо `println!` можно увидеть по [ссылке](https://gist.github.com/kudrevatykh/32b33c642998fea945a8)