# Макрос print! как использовать

Tags: rust, макросы

Пытаюсь сделать ввод и вывод данных на одной строке, т.е. хочу чтобы было так:

```
Введите число: ... //какой-то ввод
```

Использование макроса `print!`, не выводит текст сразу, он выводится когда-то потом. Как решение нашел следующее и оно работает:

```
let mut enter = String::new();
print!("Введите число:");
io::stdout().flush().unwrap();
io::stdin()
    .read_line(&mut enter)
    .expect("Ошибка чтения ввода!");
```

В документации говориться что print! и println! отличаются только переводом строки, но тогда вопрос почему `println!` срабатывает сразу, а `print!` потом. Почему так происходит? Можно ли как-то без дополнительного кода использовать `print!`, там где он уместен?

PS: видел [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431822/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B-rust/432037#432037) в котором аналогичная тема поднимается, там как раз предлагают использовать аналогичный код, но почему???

Comment: Потому что перевод строки в терминалах автоматически выполняет flush (причём при записи в файл автоматический flush выполняться уже не будет)

Comment: Не понял при чем тут перевод строки, если print, сам по себе не выводит почему-то ничего сразу при достижении этой строки ...

Comment: Не понял, что вы не поняли. Если вы в ваш print добавите перевод строки `print!("Введите число\n");`, то всё выведется сразу и без flush, потому что, как я уже ранее сказал, перевод строки в терминалах автоматически выполняет flush

Comment: Так сейчас понял, что видимо `flush` выполняется в `println` по умолчанию, а в обычном `print` нет и её нужно выполнять самим. Недопонимание остаётся в том почему без неё не обойтись и что это такое. В доке сейчас прочел, но не особо понял ...

Comment: flush выполняется не в println, а в операционной системе (или в местной стандртной библиотеке), которая видит перевод строки и делает flush. Так-то Rust тут ни при чём, во всех других языках поведение точно такое же

Comment: *(Мне казалось, что я где-то видел хорошую статью про буферизацию, но сейчас не могу её найти, ну ладно...)* В общем, при выводе чего-то куда-то данные не выводятся прям сразу, а некоторое время копятся во внутреннем буфере (его размер обычно 4096 байт или около того), потому что это позволяет улучшить производительность. Из-за этого print выводит данные не сразу: вместо вывода они кладутся в буфер. Если нужно вывести данные сейчас, нужно сбросить буфер, то есть выполнить flush. При выводе в терминал используется построчная буферизация: буфер сам сбрасывается после появления перевода строки.

Comment: Теперь стало понятнее, спасибо. С подобной штукой не сталкивался, например в python не видел такого, хотя подобную задачу (ввод и вывод в одной строке) делал. Получается без вызова этой функции `flush` сообщение аналогичным образом ни как не вывести?

Comment: В Python всё то же самое: если вы сделаете `print("Введите число:", end="")` то тоже ничего не выведется из-за того же самого буфера. Вас могло запутать то, что питоновый `input()` автоматически делает flush, но если вы вместо него используете какой-нибудь `sys.stdin.readline()` то поведение Python станет таким же как и в Rust. В целом, вызывать flush в любом случае нужно, явно или неявно

Comment: Ок, понятно, спасибо. Если перенесёте в ответ, то отмечу как правильный, может кому-то поможет

Answer (score 0):

Лучшее решение в вашем случае будет просто использовать это:

```
fn main() {
let mut enter = String::new();
eprint!("Введите число:");
io::stdin()
    .read_line(&mut enter)
    .expect("Ошибка чтения ввода!");
}
```

Я не понимаю, чем отличается eprint от print, но это работает.

Comment: Ну хоть почитал бы тогда https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.eprint.html